# Python finditer() output confusion

Tags: python, regex

I was trying this code as mentioned in docs.python:

```
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers drumming, 11 ... 10 ...')
>>> for match in iterator:
...     print (match.span())
... 
(0, 2)
(22, 24)
(29, 31)
```

where `p` was defined as

```
p = re.compile('\d+')
```

But 12,11 and 10 all are two digit numbers. So why is it showing 0-2, 22-24, 29-31?
Whats the deal with this output. Whats the benefit if any?

Comment: Where did you define `p`? What is it?

Comment: `p = re.compile('\d+')`. It's towards the end of [this section](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html?highlight=drummers%20drumming#performing-matches) of the Regular Expression HOWTO.

Answer (score 4):

The span maps nicely onto a slice. ie the end index is not included

```
>>> ['12 drummers drumming, 11 '[slice(*i)] for i in ((0,2), (22,24))]
['12', '11']
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the doc too:

> span()    Return a tuple containing the (start, end) positions of the
>   match

Prefer using `match.group` to display match *content*:

```
>>> iterator = p.finditer('12 drummers drumming, 11 ... 10 ...')
>>> for match in iterator:
    print match.group(), match.span()



12 (0, 2)
11 (22, 24)
10 (29, 31)
```

Comment: Emmanuel thanks for reply & Im sorry if I didint put it up properly but my question is that, shouldnt the start and end indexes be this -- (0,1); (22,23); (29,30) because the length of digit is only two. whereas (0,2) would mean the digit length is 3.

Comment: Oh sorry, well the start index is _included_, whereas the end index is _excluded_ - this is the same for slicing notation: `t[1:3]` only returns 2 characters (at indexes 1 and 2), not 3 !!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of [`span()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.span), [`start()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start), and `end()`, `span()` returns a tuple of the start and end of the match.

> For MatchObject m, return the 2-tuple (m.start(group), m.end(group)). Note that if group did not contribute to the match, this is (-1, -1). group defaults to zero, the entire match.

`start()` and `end()` are the indices that indicate where the matched substring exists.

> Return the indices of the start and end of the substring matched by group; group defaults to zero (meaning the whole matched substring).

So `match.span()` will return just that tuple. If you want to display the actual match, try [`match.group()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).